# Run MapReduce job from separate driver class

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I've written a small MapReduce job that works great from a single file. What I need to do now, (for a class) is drive that same MapReduce job from an separate class. I explain this below.

**What works:**

```
public class Count {

    public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
        do mapping stuff
    }

    public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
        do reducing stuff
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        runs the MR job perfectly!
    }
```

**What I need to do:**

```
// ===================== NB_train_hadoop.java =====================
public class NB_train_hadoop {

    public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
        do mapping stuff
    }

    public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
        do reducing stuff
    }



// =========================== run.java ===========================
public class run {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Run NB Count");
        // Job job = New Job(conf, "Run NB Count");

        job.setJarByClass(NB_train_hadoop.class);
        job.setMapperClass(NB_train_hadoop.TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(NB_train_hadoop.IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(NB_train_hadoop.IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get an **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: NB_train_hadoop$TokenizerMapper
    at run.main(run.java:19)** error. This points to setMapperClass line in my run.java but I don't understand why I'm getting it. The classes should be visible to to any other class in the package.

If it helps, this is how I compile, jar, and run my MR job. No errors until the the third command.

```
>>> bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main NB_train_hadoop.java run.java
>>> jar cvf run.jar run.class
>>> bin/hadoop jar run.jar run /user/nbcount/input /user/nbcount/output3
```

Any suggestions on why this is happening would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the package information of the main class or driver class in the main program or driver.
You can execute the Map reduce Job correctly with the command :-

```
 >hadoop jar <Location_of_your_JAR> <package_information_of_the_driver_class> <input_directory> <output_directory>
```

eg: For example :-
 hadoop jar /user/desktop/wordcount.jar com.example.wordcount_driver /user/cloudera/Dataset/input.txt /user/cloudera/output

Accept if the solution works !

Comment: In that case also i see that the name of your mapper is TokenizerMapper. But in the driver you have provided it as NB_train_hadoop.TokenizerMapper. There seems to be a problem. Please recheck it .

Comment: Hey Sachin, thanks for your response. It turned out I was being really dumb and overlooked the fact that I wasn't jar'ing all of my .class files, specifically **NB_train_hadoop$TokenizerMapper.class** and **NB_train_hadoop$IntSumReducer.class**. Your comment hints at this. I literally spent hours on this problem and I wish I could delete this question. Thanks for your help. I'll mark your answer as the solution to close the problem.

Comment: @Austin: Thanks for accepting my answer. You may better use Maven to easily manage all your dependencies and to package all your source code into a single JAR unit :)

Comment: I'm not a very tenured java programmer and I'm not very familiar with Maven other than it's used to manage dependencies within projects. Is it very useful from the command line and how would it have it helped me in this situation?

Comment: @Austin: I'm also a beginner in hadoop. Maven is a a project management or automation tool. You can use it here to package all your classes and dependencies(for eg: Hadoop dependencies like hadoop core). So that if you create a project as a maven project then it automatically packages all the sources and dependencies into a single unit. We can use Maven instead of a Hadoop IDE plug-in.